# VBA Code Help - Copying multiple sheets into a new workbook (for distribution)

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I am having trouble editing this vba code after recording a macro. The macro code is as per below. I am getting an error that says invalid qualifier at the line "wsSplitBU.Copy After:=Aname.Sheets(1)".

The idea here is to duplicate these 4 sheets into a whole new workbook and then pasting them as values prior to saving.

Would an expert here be able to help with the editting of the code to make this more flexible?

Thank you!

```
   Sub Data_Cleanser()


Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim wsRaw As Worksheet
Set wsRaw = Sheets("RAW DATA")
Dim wsPivot As Worksheet
Set wsPivot = Sheets("Pivot_RAW_DATA")
Dim wsPivotM As Worksheet
Set wsPivotM = Sheets("Pivot")
Dim lastRowRD As Long
lastRowRD = wsRaw.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Dim wbS As Workbook
Set wbS = Workbooks("Spend automator.xlsm")
Dim wsSplitBU As Worksheet
Set wsSplitBU = Sheets("Split BU (HUTAS)")
Dim wsLocalS As Worksheet
Set wsLocalS = Sheets("Localization Spend")
Dim wsPlantSp As Worksheet
Set wsPlantSp = Sheets("Bedok, Changi, Bandung Spend")

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'Populate formula'
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

[Aa1].Resize(lastRowRD - 1, 1).FormulaR1C1 = ("BU Correction Generator")
[Aa2].Resize(lastRowRD - 1, 1).Formula = ("=VLOOKUP(N2,'BU CORRECTOR REFERENCE'!$A:$C,3,FALSE)")

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'Refresh Pivot'
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

wsPivot.Select
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable9").PivotCache.Refresh
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotCache.Refresh
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotCache.Refresh
wsPivotM.Select
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotCache.Refresh

Dim Aname As String
Aname = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value
Workbooks.Add

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'Create new distributable workbook'
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

    wsPivotM.Copy
    wbS.Activate
    wsSplitBU.Copy After:=Aname.Sheets(1)
    wbS.Activate
    wsLocalS.Copy After:=Aname.Sheets(2)
    wbS.Activate
    wsPlantSp.Copy After:=Aname.Sheets( _
    3)
    Range("B4:M8").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Sheets("Localization Spend").Select
    Range("B3:M19").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("L1:M1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Range("L2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Split BU (HUTAS)").Select
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 9
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 3
    Range("C18:N46").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("M1:N1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Range("M2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Pivot").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=SpendReport & ".xls"


End Sub
```

Comment: `Aname` is a string variable. It have no properies at all and `.Sheets(1)` in particular. You must use a variable of `Workbook` type referenced to destination workbook.

Comment: Hi Akina. I tried to change it to the below code, but now I am getting "Object required" ? "Dim SpendReport As Workbook
Set SpendReport = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value"

Comment: Now you try to assign some scalar value to non-inited variable of Workbook type. You must get the (String type) name of destination file, then open it assigning the reference into the (Workbook type) variable.

Comment: @akina would you be able to give an example ?

Answer (score 0):

> @akina would you be able to give an example ? – Fadhilah Afif 19 mins ago

Copy sheet from this workbook to some another workbook example.

```vba
Sub copy_sheet()
    Workbooks.Open Filename:="c:\tmp\workbook2.xlsx"
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Copy Before:=Workbooks("workbook2.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet2")
    Workbooks("workbook2.xlsx").Save
    Workbooks("workbook2.xlsx").Close
End Sub
```